# Spring Boot: using SpEL collection selection from YAML in @ConditionalOnExpression

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I have a Spring Boot application with a YAML configuration that contains a feature list like this:

```
features:
  - key: feature1
    enabled: true
    description: First feature
  - key: feature2
    enabled: false
    description: Second feature
...
```

I would like to use @ConditionalOnExpression to conditionally initialize beans related to those features, identifying them by keys. Since "features" property is a list, it seems I need collection selection to do this. I have tried these two options for the annotation's value:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("${features.?[key == 'feature1'][0].enabled}")

@ConditionalOnExpression("${features}.?[key == 'feature1'][0].enabled")
```

But both give the same error on startup:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
```

If I pass the expression (without ${}) to SpelExpressionParser.parseExpression() and then evaluate it (against a list of feature objects built programmatically), it works as expected and returns the value of "enabled" property. So the expression's structure seems to be OK, and the problem is how I use it in @ConditionalOnExpression. What exactly can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spring SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions) supports only simple property placeholders inside the properties file.

If your properties file and condition code are like this, your SpEL will work:

```java
features:
  feature1:
    enabled: true
    description: First feature.
  feature2:
    enabled: false
    description: Second feature.
```

```java
@ConditionalOnExpression(
        value = "#{'${features.feature1.enabled}'.equals('true')}"
)
```

###### But if you want to load it as a map feature and use the map SpEL features;

The most elegant way is writing the [key-values as an inline JSON](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-inline-maps) (use ' and " chars to avoid cumbersome escaping) and parsing it using SpEL:

```java
features: '{
"feature1": {"enabled":"true", "description":"..."},
"feature2": {"enabled":"false", "description":"..."}
}'
```

```java
@ConditionalOnExpression(
        value = "#{${features}['feature1']['enabled'].equals('true')}"
)
```

If you had used the selection method it would have looked like this;

```java
@ConditionalOnExpression(
        value = "#{${features}.?[key=='feature1']['feature1']['enabled'].equals('true')}"
)
```

Comment: So collection selection from a list should not be used in Conditionals, right?

Comment: There is no such restriction in [collection selection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-collection-selection). The part that restricts you; the fact that you can't get complex list / map directly from YAML file in SpEL.

Answer (score 1):

`${...}` has nothing to do with SpEL; that syntax is for property placeholders in Spring.

e.g. `@Value("${property.foo:default}" String someProperty`.

This will set `someProperty` to the value of `property.foo` if present, or `default` otherwise. (the `:...` part can be omitted to force the property to exist).